# Http basic authorization with Volley Android Library

Tags: android, android-volley

I used below code to open a file but dose not work and message "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://..... " is showed. what is wrong with android and volley?

```
   StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Method.POST,url,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                pages = PageParser.parse(response);
                adapter = new DailyReportAdapter(MenuDailyReport.this,
                        pages);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                pDialog.hide();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error.printStackTrace();
                pDialog.hide();
                Toast.makeText(MenuDailyReport.this,
                        "Could not connect to server"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
        })
{

        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("username","mohammad" );
            params.put("password","mohammad123" );
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    ;
};
```

Comment: does it works using external tool like postman?

Comment: 401 reponse code is Unauthorized, I think you should review your server-side (web service) code. should not check authorization when login. If this is not login phase, use bearer token instead. Moreover, show your web service code for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the charset, must be utf-8, i thinks. So

Try to Override this methos, inside off override getheaders(), as it:

```
    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    }
```

I recommend to use Bearer Token as header, is better.
Regards.